# Gradle: interchangeably use AAR or project dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, aar

I have an AAR library that I want to distribute to partners along with a sample project that uses it. I want to also use the same sample project for manual testing while developing the AAR library. Thus, I would like to be able to use the library *project* as a dependency when developing, and the *AAR file* as a dependency when distributing.

I tried to define two flavors in the sample application:

```
    productFlavors {
       aar {}
       project {}
    }
```

...and then define dependencies like this:

```
    dependencies {
        //other dependencies
        projectCompile project(':myLibrary')
        aarCompile 'com.example.mylibrary:myLibrary-release@aar'
    }
```

The `aar` flavor builds if I comment out the dependency for the `project` flavor, but if I leave both uncommented, Gradle sync fails if the myLibrary directory is not present - despite the fact that the `project` build flavor is not part of the current build variant.

What is the correct way to do this? Or do I have to choose between creating a whole separate project for distribution or always referencing the AAR even when debugging/testing?

Comment: FWIW, in my open source libraries, my demo apps reference the library using `debugCompile project(':..')` and `releaseCompile 'com.commonsware.cwac:...'`. Hence, I use build types, not product flavors.

Comment: That is not so simple for us, since debug and release do other things in our setup such as turning on and off proguard - and we have to be able to test both scenarios during development.